# Salesforce - SharePoint integration

Tags: integration

I want to sync Salesforce opportunity stage change with the SharePoint termsheet approval stages. So when the stage move beyond stage-4 then it will check the termsheet in SharePoint at what level termsheet is approved (e.g legal,tax, finance team)
Is there any way to sync these two with each other?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.